# Custom Action bar layout not getting proper width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I am trying to use a custom layout for action bar with navigation drawer but it seems like the width is not consistent.

Here's how it looks like right now:

[ListView http://imageshack.com/a/img673/867/fTvd6X.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img673/867/fTvd6X.png)

For some reason the width is not occupied completely on the left of the action bar.

The items currently used in the custom action bar are : app name(Text View), Spinner(Some Text), ImageView on the right of Spinner.

This is how my layout xm looks like:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:src="@drawable/someIcon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appTextLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="someAppName"
        android:textColor="#555555"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/locationSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:src="@drawable/location_down_icon" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And sample code for Action bar :

```
    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    mActionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);
```

No idea whats going wrong with this.

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this a space for icon (or logo)?

you might try

```
 getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

but you have flags `ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME` and `ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP`, maybe they are important for you...

also you might try set transparent icon

```
getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
```

Comment: Tried the code.. not working.. still have that blank space on the left..:(

Comment: Do u think the problem might be cause of navigation drawer? I tried to remove the flags and its still the same

Comment: Made an edit on the layout and the action bar code.. seems to work a bit better but still some space left on the left.

Comment: if you are using Drawer be sure to use newest version from AppCompat v21. also you might set `android:homeAsUpIndicator` to null (in styles) - this removing "back" arrow, but don't remove whole morphing drawer icon (and for this you have to set setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(**true**);